# The term 'Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet error from Azure pipeline worked last week

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I put together a deployment code to deploy a network in Azure last week, all worked fine. Running the same code today I get the error below.

> The term 'Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
$peering = Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering -Name $peering_name -VirtualNetworkName $peering_record.vNetRemotePeer -ResourceGroupName $peering_record.vNetRemotePeerRG -errorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Unsure what has changed and why the error is suddenly popping up. In the Ps script, I have the line above.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
  - name: env
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values: 
      - dev

name: "Build-$(Build.Repository.Name)-${{ upper(parameters.env) }}-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)-$(Rev:rr)"

variables:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'dev') }}:
    - template: vars/dev.yml
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'test') }}:
    - template: vars/test.yml
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'uat') }}:
    - template: vars/uat.yml
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'sit') }}:
    - template: vars/sit.yml
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'prod') }}:
    - template: vars/prod.yml

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: "Deploy IAC on (${{ parameters.env }})"
        pool: 
          vmImage: windows-latest
        environment: ${{ parameters.env }}

        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:

              steps:
              - checkout: self

              - task: AzureCLI@2
                displayName: "Deploy network"
                inputs: 
                  azureSubscription: 'service_connection'
                  scriptType: 'ps'
                  scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
                  scriptPath: '.\Scripts\deploy_network.ps1'
                  arguments: "-DeploymentResourceGroup: '${{ variables.resourceGroupName }}' -TemplateFile: './IAC/iac/main.bicep' -ParameterFile: './ADO/Pipelines/envs/${{upper(parameters.env)}}.json' "
```

Comment: Are you running with same user account?  Did you try starting PS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: This is from Azure devops and not from a windows terminal.

Comment: It is still using a windows credential.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is related to the fact that AzureRM and AZ both were installed on the agent.

What I did was to change the Ps code to use Az modules only.

Instead of
`$peering = Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering -Name $peering_name -VirtualNetworkName $peering_record.vNetRemotePeer -ResourceGroupName $peering_record.vNetRemotePeerRG -errorAction SilentlyContinue`

I used

`az network vnet peering show`

This means that the pipeline would call a script that made use of `Az` modules only.